# How to wrap in span last three words from string / heading

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to wrap last three words from string that will be a heading on site. I am trying with split method and with pop but not getting it.

```
 var text = "This is an example text sentence"
```

i would like to look in html like this
This is an an example text sentence

```
var split = text.split(" ");
var last = split.pop() // but it gives me only the last word 

text.join(" ") + (text.length > 0 ?
' <span class="text-stroke">' + last + "</span>" : last)
```

Comment: insert more code pls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match `\s+\S+` (spaces, followed by non-spaces) as many times as you want to match a word, followed by `$` (the end of the string):

```js
var text = "This is an example text sentence"
const newHTML = text.replace(
  /(?:\s+\S+){3}$/,
  '<span>$&</span>'
);
console.log(newHTML);
```

Comment: This is good, but I think `This is an<span> example...` should rather be `This is an <span>example...`

Comment: Nice it worked :D but what if, there will be two spans so that the heading will look like this  This is an <span class="a"> example <span class="b">ext sentence</span></span> is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

```js
// split your text by spaces
let text = "This is an example text sentence.".split(/\s+/)

// rejoin your text
let nexText = text.slice(0, text.length-3).join(' ')
    + ' <span>'
    + text.slice(text.length-3).join(' ')
    + '</span>'

console.log(nexText)
// => This is an <span>example text sentence.</span>
```